# Tool "Code Map" of VS2012 in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-map

I'd like to use Code Map, which can be used in Visual Studio 2012, also in Visual Studio 2010.

If you don't know what Code Map is, this is how it looks like:

[image]

here's a tutorial from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn194476.aspx

Is it somehow possible to use this in VS2010 or is there any similiar tools, which displays the different method calls? By this I want to display a method `Method1()` which calls another method called `Method2()`. This should be displayed like in the CodeMap (not by using hierarchy call, I want to see it with a UI). It should be free or an extension for VS2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a free version that offers something that the Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Edition offers, but you have a few alternatives:

- [NDepend features a Call Graph option](http://www.ndepend.com/doc_vs_arch.aspx)
- You can open the VS2010 solution in VS2012
- [Debugger Canvas offers a similar feature while debugging](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4a979842-b9aa-4adf-bfef-83bd428a0acb)
- [Architecture Explorer Dependency Graphs and Sequence Diagrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx)